# Adjacency matrix of a graph with labeled edges

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Is it possible to represent this graph with a adjacency matrix? How I can do that?

[image: Graph G]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.

In an adjacency matrix a $1$ in row $A$, column $B$ represents the presence of an edge from $A$ to $B$. In a graph like yours where there are multiple edges between two vertices you could put the number of edges at that place in the matrix. But if the edges have labels that won't capture all the information you need.

If you had to deal with this structure in a computer program you could use a list of edge labels for a pair of vertices.

Another possibility would be to create new vertices for the edges, labeled $4$, $5$ and $6$ in your example, and join each of $A$ and $B$ to those three. The adjacency matrix for that five vertex bipartite graph has all the information in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is a two dimensional array. There are three edges between two vertices. You cannot write it by adjacency matrix. But you may represent it by an adjacency tensor as follows.
$$a_{112} = 4, a_{121} = 4;$$
$$a_{212} = 5, a_{221} = 5;$$
$$a_{312} = 6, a_{321} = 6;$$
Remaining all positions are zeros.

If you are familiar to the ideas of line graph, you may represent the edges of the graph $G$, by the vertices of a new graph, $H$. Also, the vertices of $G$ will convert to edges of $H$. In this case $H$ will contain thee vertices. You may write the adjacency matrix of the line graph of your graph. It may be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Basically adjacency matrix assumes $a_{i,j} = 1$ if there exist a link from i to j.  In your case there exist a link between 1 and 2. Hence adjacency matrix for the above undirected graph will be $\begin{array}{cc}0 1\\1 0\end {array}$. If you wanted weighted adjacency matrix,  it will be 15 instead of 1. Or if you wanted to consider three links separately you may assume dummy nodes.